# Button that performs a function (on slides)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides

I saw that in the spreadsheet you can create a drawing and link to a function in the script.

I need to: Create a button or link where clicking it will perform a function in the script.
It will be a simple email sending function.

Example: When the user clicks the button or link in the presentation, they receive an email from them.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: ! ! ! ! ! ! ! See - Star - Comment in Issue tracker! ! ! ! ! ! !    
"Page elements on Slides should be selectable to run scripts like the shapes and images in spreadsheet"   https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/186214943

"Presentation mode in slides should fill window not device"  https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/186204484

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to assign a script to a button in Google Slides in the same way as there is in Google Sheets.

The only alternative would be to use either a [simple](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/) or [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) depending on your needs.

Google Slides only has compatibility with the `onOpen()` and `onInstall()` simple triggers [which you can see here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#available_types_of_triggers), though you would be able to send the mail with the built-in Apps Script library as such:

```gas
function sendEmail() {
  MailApp.sendEmail("username@domain.com", "subject", "body");
}
```

Comment: what is the use of the pageElement.onSelect? Is it visible to an installed trigger?